# PHP readfile doesn't work, but only for 20+ meg files

Tags: php, header, readfile

Small script, being used to send one of two .pdf files to the user based on the get string:

```
if ($fileToSend == "bigone") { 
   $filename = "largefile.pdf";
   $header = "application/pdf";
} else if ($fileToSend == "smallone") { 
   $filename = "smallfile.pdf";
   $header = "application/pdf";
}
if (file_exists('d/' . $filename)){
    header('Content-type: ' . $header);
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);   
    readfile('d/' . $filename);
} else { 
    echo('No good');
}
```

Both files d/smallfile.pdf and d/largefile.pdf exist. smallfile.pdf is about 5megs. largefile.pdf is about 25megs.

sendFile.php?fileToSend=smallone works.

sendFile.php?fileToSend=bigone doesn't work; in FF, it says

File not found
Firefox can't find the file at [url]/sendFile.php?fileToSend=bigone

There are no filename errors.

I've tried

- Adding flush(); prior to the readfile; this causes the download file dialogue box to appear, but then serves a 0 byte file
- Adding flush(); prior to the readfile, and adding header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('d/' . $filename)); - this works successfully, but takes close to 2 minutes to process (ie, once I hit the URL, nothing happens for close to 2 minutes, and then the dialogue box appears with the actual file to download in it correctly).

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Jon

Comment: Have you tried increasing PHP's memory limit?

Comment: No; interesting idea. Would that cause this behavior? I'll ask my admin.

Comment: You can also do this yourself using `ini_set` if allowed. `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your problem is most likely php timing out while feeding you the file, a remedy for this is to feed you chunks so as not to chew memory and `set_time_limit(0);` so it wont timeout after 60s:

```
 <?php 
 if(isset($_GET['fileToSend'])){

    switch($_GET['fileToSend']){
        case "bigone":
            if(downloadFile("./d/largefile.pdf")===false){
                //failed, do somthing
            }
            break;

        case "smallone":
            if(downloadFile("./d/smallfile.pdf")===false){
                //failed, do something
            }
            break;

        default:
            echo 'No file selected';
            break;

    }

 }

 function downloadFile($file){
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        if(is_dir($file)){return false;}
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file)).'"';
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

        ob_clean();
        $handle = fopen($file, "rb");
        $chunksize=(filesize($file)/1024);

        set_time_limit(0);
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            echo fgets($handle, $chunksize);
            flush();
        }
        fclose($handle);
        die;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Lawrence - I'll give that a shot. For what it's worth, File not found returns instantly, so I'm not sure it's a timeout issue, but I'll try.

Comment: Glad to have helped, also by changing the chunk size `1024` you can limit download speeds.

Comment: Be careful with the use of `ob_clean();` here.. If you haven't started an output buffer, and the error settings haven't been set properly, it will generate an error rendering the downloaded file useless.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the download takes too much time and hits your PHP script's timeout?

A cleaner solution would be to redirect to the correct file if it's possible and let the web server handle it directly.

```
<?php header('Location: http://www.example.com/d/' . $filename) ;?>
```

Comment: I would rather serve the file myself, for a few reasons (including because it's protected by a username and unique token, and because I don't want google to crawl it).

Answer (score 0):

When streaming a file, make sure that you have output buffering disabled. Otherwise PHP with buffer the whole file. In your case, PHP is probably running out of memory because it is buffering the whole file. Add the ob_clean, flush before readfile:

```
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile('d/' . $filename);
```

The browser will not timeout as long as it is receiving data, so the download can take 10 minutes if it needs to.